# Is there a default radiation intensity in radon transform of matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am doing some simple labs with radon transform,  and I'm just curious about one thing.

I know that, the radon transform function will return a column which is the attenuation in the radiation intensity. And I'm looking for if there's the default radiation intensity to compute the attenuation, or it just simply computes the linear integrals.

Here's my code:

```
I = zeros(200, 200);
I(50:150, 50:150) = 1;
figure; imshow(I);  title('Original image');


[R, xp] = radon(I,[0, 45]);
figure; plot(xp, R(:, 1)); title('Radiance Intensity'); 

theta = 0:180;
[R1, xp1] = radon(I, theta);


figure; imagesc(theta, xp1, R1); colormap(hot); colorbar;
xlabel('{\theta} (degrees)'); ylabel('x{\prime}'); title('Sine figure');


I1 = iradon(R1, theta);

figure; imshow(I1);  title('Reconstructed image');
```

Comment: Its linear integrals. if with "radiation" you are thinking about CT (otherwise not sure what part of the Radon transform "radiates"), then no, the transform itself does not tell you how much radiation there is. Is this what you mean?  I can expand on it if it is.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, I have been confused for so long.

Comment: Can you elaborate in your confusion? I am still not sure what you are asking. The radon transform has nothing to do with the energy of the photons.

Comment: Sorry to reply to u for too long.  You know that when I create a square(called I) that is 200 x 200, and the center of I ( I(50:150, 50:150) = 1). And when I get its projection through 0 °, the max attenuation intensity I get is  101, close to 100.  I know that the thickness of the white square, which is the  I(50:150, 50:150) = 1, is 100. And I was thinking that if the attenuation intensity is just 100 * 1 * the default radiation intensity (which I thought was 1), and the answer is 101? I am not  familiar with the Principle of CT images, so I was confused by my thoughts.

Comment: Unless you are using a physics simulator code of X-ray and matter interactions, there is no physics in the code. Its sums  of line lengths multiplied by pixel values. You showed no code, so you can not get help with the code. But please forget about radiation intensity, such thing is only applicable in physics, the radon transform is a mathematical operator.

Comment: thank u for your patient explain! I may already know about it, and I have post my code to the answer, I would be more glad if you can have a look at it!

Comment: `I(50:150, 50:150) = 1;` fills up 101 values per column/row.... You simply don't understand well matlab indexing, it has nothing to do with the radon transform.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake just now, I am the first time to use stackoverflow,. And I will pay attention to it in the future. Well, I exactly don't understand matlab indexing. My confuse disappears right now. Thank u so much!    :)

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/radon.html) does a pretty good job of explaining what the algorithm does.